# ToolTip - does not work after refresh the div

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I ask you for help. Namely, struggling with the tooltip in ajax.  Everything works beautifully when the page is load or after such as F5. However, in the part web I use refresh div every 60 seconds by ajax

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#loaddiv').load('refresh_clusterdx_2.php');
}, 60000);
</script>
```

The code of my tooltip

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function showProfileTooltip(e, id){
            var top = e.clientY -45;
            var left = e.clientX + 25;

            $('.p-tooltip').css({
                'top':top,
                'left':left
            }).show();
            //send id & get info from get_prefix.php
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Info/get_prefix.php?id='+id,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('.p-tooltip').html('Loading..');
                },
                success: function(html){
                    $('.p-tooltip').html(html);
                }
            });
        }

        function hideProfileTooltip(){
            $('.p-tooltip').hide();
        }

        $('.profile').mouseover(function(e){
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            showProfileTooltip(e, id);
        });

        $('.p-tooltip').mouseleave(function(){
            hideProfileTooltip();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

All beautifully and looks ok until the div is not refreshed. When a div to be refreshed, the tooltip no work :(  I can not find a solution to the problem, whether it is at all possible to solve.
Thank you for any help.
Regards
tjakob

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your functions work after ajax loaded content, you'll have to modify them a little:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.profile', function() {
      var id = $('.profile').attr('data-id');
      showProfileTooltip(e, id);
});


$(document).on('mouseleave', '.p-tooltip', function() {
      hideProfileTooltip();
});
```

You should always use .on with dynamically loaded content - I'm in the habit of doing this for all my functions now.

Comment: tnx Jason for your answer, but if i use this modify the ToolTip does not work at all, even when first load the page  :(

Comment: hmm, this is a see black magic for me O.o  and increasingly it is incomprehensible for me, my head probably already too old for such thinking.

Comment: Ok, the tooltip work with this code :        $(document).on('mouseover', '.profile', function(e) {
      var id = $('.profile').attr('data-id');
      showProfileTooltip(e, id);
});


$(document).on('mouseleave', '.p-tooltip', function() {
      hideProfileTooltip();
});      But after refresh still stop working

Comment: WOW work!!!! Topic can be closed!  Yes i need change the '.profile' to $this and the ToolTip div put before our refresh div  '#loaddiv' Many TNX Ryan and Jason, best Regards!